# Eclipse Certification Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a `Maven repository` that is in my company server so I have to use a certificate to connect.

i had to modify my `mvn` command and add these lines:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/maven/bin/maven.jks
export MAVEN_OPTS=$MAVEN_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=123456
export MAVEN_OPTS=$MAVEN_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS
export MAVEN_OPTS=$MAVEN_OPTS -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true
export MAVEN_OPTS=$MAVEN_OPTS -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
```

After that I added this certificate to my `cacerts` file here:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

I also modify my installed Maven settings.xml file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>companyrepo.group</id>
            <name>companyrepo.group</name>
            <url>https://companyrepo.intra/companyrepo.group</url>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>companyrepo.group</id>
                    <url>https://companyrepo.intra/companyrepo.group</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>                                                                                             
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
    </activeProfiles>
     <proxies>
    </proxies>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>companyrepo.group</id>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

And also set my Eclipse to use this settings file.

If I try to connect this repo from my terminal I can access, for example if I run `mvn package` command I can connect to this repo.

After that I set my Eclipse/Preferences/Maven/Installation to not use the build in default `Maven` but if I open a project that use this company repository i got this error message:

```
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 from https://companyrepo.intra/companyrepo.group was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until 
 the update interval of companyrepo.group has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 from/to companyrepo.group (https://companyrepo.intra/companyrepo.group): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to 
 requested target
```

Where should I set this `jks` to make `Eclipse` see the repository? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `MAVEN_OPTS` variables are available to the `mvn` script but eclipse plugin doesn't use the script but its own mechanism to execute maven commands. To pass the arguments to maven plugin, in the "Edit Configuration and launch" dialog in Eclipse:

**Run As** > **Maven Build** > Click on the **JRE** tab > Enter **VM args** e.g.

> ${env_var:MAVEN_OPTS}

Comment: Thank you! i don't want to build my project from Eclipse, but sometimes want to deploy to Weblogic server. Where should i put then the VM args?